# Isomorphism of directed graphs

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

Consider the following directed graphs:

[image: Directed graph]
[image: Directed graph]

One is obtained from the other by reversing the direction of all edges.

Are they isomorphic as **directed** graphs ?

On the one hand, I would answer: no because there is no pair of maps between the vertices and the edges respectively that preserves the adjacency relation.

On the other hand, if one forgets about the ``labels'' on say, the edges, then the graphs are the same (just exchange the label 'e' with label 'f').

Comment: I don't get why you say that `there is no pair of maps ... that preserves the adjacency relation`. You even describe such map in the next sentence (`exchange the label 'e' with label 'f'`). What am I missing?

Comment: A graph morphism is a pair of maps between the respective set of vertices $p:V \to V$ and and between the respective set of edges $q:E \to E$. If I set $q(e) = f$, $q(f) = e$ and $q(l) = l$ then because of the adjacency relation, I have to set:
w = initial vertex of f = initial vertex of q(e) = p(initial vertex of e) = p(v).
So p has to exchange $v$ and $w$.
Now $q(l) = l$ so again by the adjacency relation one must have:
$v$ = initial of vertex of $l$ = initial vertex of $q(l)$ = $p$(initial vertex of $l$) = $p(v)$.
Hence $p$ has to fix the vertex $v$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: Ah, I think I see your problem. You need to rename edges on one of the graphs. For example, for the right graph name edges $e'$ and $f'$. Edge names are not part of the definition of the graph anyway.

Comment: @D.Dmitriy I agree that edge names are irrelevant but I do not see how this removes the contradiction.

Comment: In your logic you implicitly (and wrongly) assume that edge $f$ in the left graph is the same as edge $f$ on the right graph. The confusion is only due to name clash. Renaming should save you from this mistake.

Comment: Compare : "$q(e) = f$ ... $w$ = initial vertex of $f$". And after rename this statement will be: $q(e) = f'$ ... $w$ = initial vertex of $f$".

Comment: @D.Dmitriy Oh now I think I see why you're 100% right. Thanks a lot. How can I credit you for your answer ?

Comment: Glad it helped! I'll turn my comment into answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment helps clarify the source of your confusion:

> A graph morphism is a pair of maps between the respective set of vertices $p:V \to V$ and and between the respective set of edges $q:E \to E$. If I set $q(e) = f$, $q(f) = e$ and $q(l) = l$ then because of the adjacency relation, I have to set: $w = \text{initial vertex of } f = \text{initial vertex of } q(e) = p(\text{initial vertex of e})= p(v)$. So $p$ has to exchange $v$ and $w$. Now $q(l) = l$ so again by the adjacency relation one must have: $v = \text{initial of vertex of } l = \text{initial vertex of } q(l) = p(\text{initial vertex of } l) = p(v)$. Hence $p$ has to fix the vertex $v$. This is a contradiction.

You implicitly (and wrongly) assume that edge $f$ in the left graph is the same as edge $f$ in the right graph. The confusion is only due to name clash. Renaming should save you from this mistake.

If we named edges in the right graph $e'$ and $f'$, then instead of writing this statement (original):

> $q(e) = f$, ... $w$ = initial vertex of $f$

we would have written this statement:

> $q(e) = f'$, ... $w$ = initial vertex of $f$